# Textbook about German in Bengali?

Tags: book, reference

Does someone know a textbook for learning German which is written in Bengali (Bangla)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be **Ek mashe jarman shikhun** type of book in local bookstore. You can check out these two:

1. [some PDF's](http://www.india.diplo.de/Vertretung/indien/en/04__Kolkata/04__03__Kolkata/Learning__German/seite__learn__german__kolkata.html) from Learning German in Kolkata
2. [1000+ Übungen Deutsch - Bengali](http://www.amazon.in/1000-%C3%9Cbungen-Deutsch-ChitChat-WorldWide-ebook/dp/B00NFAT4KY/)